# Cannot insert data to list - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, list, insert

Currently stuck at the moment as i am unable to insert values into lists.

I am returned the following error while trying to input into list 'sex':

'AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert''

This is what I've got so far:

```
#input/error handling
error = 'Error, Incorrect (format/value)'
returned = 'Returned.'
entryRem = 'Entry removed.'
na = 'N/A'

#data storage
index = [0]
sex = [0]
choice = int()

def menu():
    print('1. Input data')
    input1 = input('Input (1): ')
    if input1 == '1':
        indexSel(index)
        sexInput(sex, choice)
    else:
        print('\n',error,returned,'\n')
        menu()
        return

def indexSel(index):
    global choice
    print('Index: ',index)
    choice = len(index)
    index.append(choice)
    return

def sexInput(choice, sex):
    inSex = input("Person's Sex? (m/f)").upper()
    if inSex == 'M' or inSex == 'F':
        sex.insert(choice,inSex)
    else:
        print(entryRem,error)
    return
menu()
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. `return` on its own is also bad style. Overall, there is definitely some refactoring to be done.

Answer (score 2):

In main, you call sexInput with the following section:

```
if input1 == '1':
    indexSel(index) 
    sexInput(sex, choice)
```

Then, your header for the function reads:

```
def sexInput(choice, sex):
```

So, you switched the order, thereby making choice (an int) in what you thought would be sex (a list)

Comment: Thanks man, didnt realise this could create errors, will keep in mind in the future